# GNU Octave, convert matrix to a String

Tags: matrix, octave

In GNU Octave I have a 1xn matrix:

```
octave:1> s=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7]
s =

   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7
```

I would like to convert this matrix to a space delimited string like this:

```
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7"
```

I tried using `mat2str` and `cellstr` without much success.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Octave, How to convert matrix to string:**

If your matrix is a single column, invert it so it is a row like this:

```
octave:1> s=[1;2;3;4;5;6;7]
s =

   1
   2
   3
   4
   5
   6
   7

mat2str(s')
```

Which prints:

```
ans = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

This looks like it is not a string because it has left and right square brackets, but it is a string.  You can remove the left and right brackets like this:

```
 substr(s,2,length(s)-2)
```

Which cuts off the first and last characters, which prints:

```
 s = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Which is a string.